# XAML: access to controls inside user control

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone

I have userControl like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Image Source="/Images/btn1_normal@2x.png" Stretch="Fill" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="Text" Text="Button" Foreground="Black"
               VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

I use this userControl in another XAML like this:

```
<MyControlls:MyButton Width="90" Height="55"/>
```

Now how I can access to textBlock named Text in this XAML and change his text (in Windows phone 8)?
Something like this:

```
<MyControlls:MyButton Width="90" Height="55">
    <MyButton.Text Text="Hello World!" />        
</MyControlls:MyButton>`
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Becel.Controls.MyButton"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
x:Name="MyUserControll">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Image x:Name="myImage" Source="/Images/btn1.9_normal@2x.png" Stretch="Fill"
MouseEnter="Image_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="Image_MouseLeave" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="textTitle" Text="{Binding Title, ElementName=MyUserControll}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" FontSize="25"  MouseEnter="Image_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="Image_MouseLeave"/>

</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And in C# code :

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Title", typeof (String), typeof(MyButton),null);

    public String Title
    {
        get { return (String)GetValue(TitleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TitleProperty, value); }
    }
```

And then in everywhere you can use like this:

```
<MyUserControl:MyButton Width="90" Height="55" Margin="10 0 0 0" Title="Hello Wold!" />
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that directly. Here are two alternatives.

### Solution 1 : use a ViewModel

Use a view model class to store the properties that you need to display in your custom control.

```
class MyButtonViewModel
{
    public string Text { get;set; }
}
```

MyButton.xaml:

```
<TextBlock Text={Binding Text} ...
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window.Resources>
    <MyButtonViewModel x:Key="myButtonVm" Text="Hello!" />
</Window.Resources>

<MyButton DataContext={StaticResource myButtonVm} />
```

This use the MVVM pattern. See [WPF Apps With The Model-View-ViewModel Design Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx), if you never used it.

### Solution 2 : use a CustomControl

Replace your `UserControl` by a `CustomControl`. In that case `Text` can be a dependency property, so that you can write.

```
<MyButton Text="Hello !" />
```

This is much more complex. See [How to Create a WPF Custom Control](http://wpftutorial.net/HowToCreateACustomControl.html).

### Which to choose ?

If you intend to use your control in several different projects, and you need to be able to change the skin of the control, choose the `UserControl`.

Otherwise, go for the `ViewModel` and eventually apply the MVVM pattern in the remaining off your project.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but 
I develop Windows Phone 8 app (not WPF).
Is there way to create CustomControl in WP8 ?

Comment: See this http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/03/07/creating-custom-controls-for-metro-style-apps.aspx (Building a deployable custom control for XAML Metro style apps)

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this task, one solution could be to declare a [Dependency Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.aspx) into your `Control` (which seems to be called "MyButton") code behind :

```
  public string ButtonText
  {
    get { return (string )this.GetValue(ButtonTextProperty); }
    set { this.SetValue(ButtonTextProperty, value); } 
  }
  public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "ButtonText", typeof(string), typeof(MyButton),new PropertyMetadata(false));
```

Then you have to bind to it into your xaml code :

```
  <YourControl x:Name="MyButtonName">
    ... // some xaml code
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Image Source="/Images/btn1_normal@2x.png" Stretch="Fill" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="Text" Text="Button" Foreground="Black"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   Text="{Binding Path=ButtonText, ElementName=MyButtonName}"/>
    </Grid>
 </YourControl>
```

Finally, you are able to use your "MyButton" `Control` :

```
<MyControlls:MyButton Width="90" Height="55" ButtonText="Hello World!">
</MyControlls:MyButton>
```