# Binding data to custom UserControl

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-phone

I want bind ObservableCollection my custom UserControl but when I want add new element and I almost done but when I want add new element to collection my app crash with no reason. I thought maybe it is variable inconsistency. But I came with nothig trying with object/String/string. Maybe I done something wrong at start?

Custom UserControl XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="backtrackPrototype.checklistItem"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    d:DesignHeight="80" d:DesignWidth="480">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <TextBlock 
            x:Name="label" 
            MaxHeight="407"  
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Margin="0,17,0,16" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Text="{Binding Path=Title, ElementName=checklistItem}"/>
        <CheckBox x:Name="checkbox" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Checked="checkbox_Checked" Unchecked="checkbox_Unchecked" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Custom UserControl

```
public partial class checklistItem : UserControl 
{ 

      public string Title
      {
          get { return (string)this.GetValue(TitleProperty); }
          set { this.SetValue(TitleProperty, value); } 
      }

      // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
      public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Title", typeof(string), typeof(checklistItem), new PropertyMetadata(0));  

      public checklistItem() 
      {
            InitializeComponent();
      }

      public bool isChecked() 
      {
          if ((bool)checkbox.IsChecked) return true;
          return false;
      }

      private void checkbox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
      {
          //title.Foreground = Application.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentColor"];
          label.Foreground = (SolidColorBrush)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentBrush"];
      }

      private void checkbox_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
      {
          label.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
      }
}
```

XAML in main page

```
<ListBox Height="479" ItemsSource="{Binding}" x:Name="CheckList">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:checklistItem Title="{Binding Title}" Width="397"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox
```

CS in main page
public ObservableCollection ListItems = new ObservableCollection();

```
ListItem item = new ListItem("Nowe",false);
ListItems.Add(item);
CheckList.DataContext = ListItems;
```

And finally List

```
public class ListItem 
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }

    public ListItem(string title, bool isChecked=false) 
    {
        Title = title;
        Checked = isChecked;
    }  
}
```

I need someone who will look at code with fresh mind. Thank you.

---

### UPDATE:

What's more for accessing controls in my CustomControl I use first anwser in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491951/xaml-access-to-controls-inside-user-control) .
Also I update my UserControl XAML.

---

### UPDATE V2

When I'm using `<TextBox Title="{Binding Title}" Width="397"/>` insted of `local:checklistItem` it work just fine.

---

### UPDATE V3

OK turns out that I didn't add proper DataContext to my UserControl so now checklistItem constructor looks like this

```
public checklistItem() {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;
}
```

And controls are adding correctly but now binding for Title is not working. Because when I hardcode some title it working, binding not. But the same binding is working for default textbox.

Comment: Ofc I was hoping there is some obvious mistake... I will use `try{}catch{}`

Comment: well even if it's obvious you have provided some code, so it would take some time to check every single line, not to mention without IDE it could be really uneffective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to set the itemsSource rather than the DataContext. Setting DataContext on a Listbox will NOT generate the templated items

take out

```
ItemsSource="{Binding}"
```

from the Xaml
and change

```
CheckList.DataContext = ListItems;
```

to

```
CheckList.ItemsSource = ListItems;
```

Comment: Oh wait... my bad. It's working for Textbox, but not for custom userControl :(

Comment: Additionally take out the ElementName=checkListItem from the TextBlock in user control. I've just tested this and it works fine.

Comment: I remove it and change property name to ItemName (title prop, and title in listItem was confusing). I do as you say but atm I got `System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error: 'Title' property not found on 'backtrackPrototype.checklistItem' 'backtrackPrototype.checklistItem' (HashCode=30364973). BindingExpression: Path='Title' DataItem='backtrackPrototype.checklistItem' (HashCode=30364973); target element is 'backtrackPrototype.checklistItem' (Name=''); target property is 'ItemName' (type 'System.String')..`

Comment: I'm guessing source of that problem is setting `this.DataContext = this` in userControl. I remove it but now `System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error: 'ItemName' property not found on 'backtrackPrototype.ListItem' 'backtrackPrototype.ListItem' (HashCode=10896307). BindingExpression: Path='ItemName' DataItem='backtrackPrototype.ListItem' (HashCode=10896307); target element is 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock' (Name='label'); target property is 'Text' (type 'System.String')..
`

Comment: OK all signs in code says that property in UserControl and property in CustomClass ... becaus now it is woking fine :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that perhaps your binding in the XAML is incorrect. Your element name in the binding is LayoutRoot which is the name of your grid not your UserControl.

It is probably trying to find a property on the Grid called Title which it does not have.

Comment: I already update xaml, but still nothig. I'm trying catch someting but it isn't problem at DataContext.